# Dynamic where clause using "execute immediate USING" clause

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to dynamically add the where clause parameters.

```
  GETRESULTSET:='SELECT PARENT_PARTYID,PARTY_ID,PRODUCT_ID,PRODUCT_STATUS,BILLING_TYPE,CRMTIMESTAMP,UPDATEDTIMESTAMP,UPDATEDBY FROM     ENT_MAP_CUST_PRODUCT WHERE PARENT_PARTYID=:PARENT_PARTYID';

  IF(PRODUCT_ID IS NOT NULL) THEN
    GETRESULTSET := GETRESULTSET || ' AND  PRODUCT_ID=:PRODUCT_ID ';
  END IF; 

  IF(PRODUCT_STATUS IS NOT NULL) THEN
    GETRESULTSET := GETRESULTSET || ' AND PRODUCT_STATUS=:PRODUCT_STATUS ';
  END IF; 

    IF(BILLING_TYPE IS NOT NULL) THEN
    GETRESULTSET := GETRESULTSET || ' AND BILLING_TYPE=:BILLING_TYPE ';
  END IF;
```

Now I need to bulk collect into collection type:

```
execute immediate GETRESULTSET  bulk collect into V_PARTY_TBL USING <<>> ?
```

Now at runtime I do not know the where clause formed, so how to handle that in `USING` clause of `execute immeditate` statement.

Answer (score 2):

Add a single where clause that takes all three parameters:

```
and (PRODUCT_ID IS NULL or PRODUCT_ID=:PRODUCT_ID )
and (PRODUCT_STATUS IS NULL or PRODUCT_STATUS=:PRODUCT_STATUS)
and (BILLING_TYPE IS NULL or BILLING_TYPE=:BILLING_TYPE)
```

Then

```
execute immediate your_query 
   into your_result
  using p_product_id, 
        p_product_status, 
        p_billing_type;
```

Comment: this may solve the purpose ,but is it the best way to do this ?

Comment: With only the little piece of code you provided it's hard to tell.

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest way if to add permanent set of parameters:

```
if product_id is not null
  then sql := sql || ' and product_id = :product_id';
  else sql := sql || ' and :product_id is null';
end if;
```

But generally your task shows that you prefer a wrong way. You're trying to 'all-on-procedures' approach and faces one of it's nasty disadvantages.

Comment: what is the disadvantage?